# jpa - list OneToMany not saved

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, one-to-many

I have the below room entity which has many disponibilities, when i add a room with a list of disponibilities, the room is saved but the list is not. what am i missing in the relationship ?

```
@Entity
public class RoomEntity {

    @Id
    private String classRoomId;

    private String label;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "room", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<DisponibilityEntity> disponibilities;

    public void addDisponibilities(List<DisponibilityEntity> disponibilityEntities) {
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(disponibilities)) {
            disponibilities = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        disponibilities.addAll(disponibilityEntities);
        disponibilityEntities.forEach(item -> item.setRoom(this));
    }

}


@Entity
public class DisponibilityEntity {

    @Id
    private String disponibilityId;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_room")
    private RoomEntity room;
}

roomEntity.addDisponibilities(classRoomEntity.getDisponibilities());
roomRepository.save(roomEntity);
```

Comment: Are you sure that `classRoomEntity.getDisponibilities()` is not null/empty when you add them to a room: `roomEntity.addDisponibilities(classRoomEntity.getDisponibilities());` ?